# How to compile rusqlite 0.20.0 with cargo

Tags: sqlite, rust

I'm trying to add sqlite support in my rust project. [I found rusqlite on crates.io.](https://crates.io/crates/rusqlite) I added the version line to Cargo.toml. I added some imports (unused) that I found on the [rusqlite docs page](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/0.19.0/rusqlite/index.html). After running car go build I revived an error.

I hadn't implemented anything yet. I just wanted to get the dependency added and compiling. main.rs:

```rust
extern crate rusqlite;

use rusqlite::{Connection, Result};
use rusqlite::NO_PARAMS;
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "program"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["97"]

[dependencies]
argparse = "0.2.2"
rand = "0.4.0"
rusqlite = "0.20.0"
```

Error recived:

```
$ cargo build
   Compiling pkg-config v0.3.16
   Compiling fallible-iterator v0.2.0
   Compiling memchr v2.2.1
   Compiling bitflags v1.2.1
   Compiling lru-cache v0.1.2
error[E0432]: unresolved import `std::ops::Bound`
  --> /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/pkg-config-0.3.16/src/lib.rs:72:16
   |
72 | use std::ops::{Bound, RangeBounds};
   |                ^^^^^ no `Bound` in `ops`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `std::ops::RangeBounds`
  --> /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/pkg-config-0.3.16/src/lib.rs:72:23
   |
72 | use std::ops::{Bound, RangeBounds};
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^ no `RangeBounds` in `ops`

error[E0658]: `dyn Trait` syntax is unstable (see issue #44662)
   --> /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/pkg-config-0.3.16/src/lib.rs:143:32
    |
143 |     fn cause(&self) -> Option<&dyn error::Error> {
    |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to 3 previous errors

error: Could not compile `pkg-config`.
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error[E0658]: `crate` in paths is experimental (see issue #45477)
  --> /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/fallible-iterator-0.2.0/src/lib.rs:98:5
   |
98 | use crate::imports::*;
   |     ^^^^^

error[E0658]: `dyn Trait` syntax is unstable (see issue #44662)
    --> /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/fallible-iterator-0.2.0/src/lib.rs:2606:24
     |
2606 | fn _is_object_safe(_: &dyn DoubleEndedFallibleIterator<Item = (), Error = ()>) {}
     |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

error: Could not compile `fallible-iterator`.
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

---

**Edit**

cargo 0.26.0 (41480f5cc 2018-02-26)

rustc 1.25.0 (84203cac6 2018-03-25)

Comment: Are you perhaps running an old version of Rust? Have you updated recently? `Bound` was added in `1.17.0` and `RangeBounds` in `1.28.0`.

Comment: @loganfsmyth `cargo --version [RET] cargo 0.26.0 (41480f5cc 2018-02-26)`

Comment: @loganfsmyth (Sorry. Forgot cargo and rustc are not the same.) rustc 1.25.0 (84203cac6 2018-03-25). It must be `RangeBounds` then. Do you know which version of rusqlite works with rust 1.25?

Comment: I don't know, and there isn't guaranteed to be one. Would you be able to update? As you can see from that date, your version is more than a year and a half behind.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I could probably update. Just run *rustup* again, right?

Comment: @loganfsmyth I just ran *rustup* for linux and it gave me 1.25 again. Is there a way to tell *rustup* which version I want?

Comment: rustc 1.38.0 (625451e37 2019-09-23) https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/edition-guide/rust-2018/rustup-for-managing-rust-versions.html after running `rustup install stable` not run from web.

Comment: Does that version seem to work with `rusqlite`?

Comment: @loganfsmyth Thanks. It was the old version of rust. I ran cargo again and it complied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most crates support only the latest Rust version. You could try to use an older version of the crate, but the easiest way is to update Rust to a currently-supported version.

If you're using Rust from a Linux distro, then uninstall it, and get it from https://rustup.rs which can keep it up to date. Rust ecosystem moves much faster than most distributions.

Run `rustup update`.